# Only insert the data from the first table that doesn't exist in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to figure out how to insert the data to the second table from the first table, but I don't want to insert the existing data that the second table already had from previous injection. Is there any way to check before it inserts the data?

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
INSERT INTO content2 (d1, d2, d3) SELECT d1, d2, d3 FROM content
```

I tried to put "LIMIT 1" into the query, but it didn't work. I'm not sure if I had it in the right place...

Comment: You will have to use a transaction to select the value from the first table, if not exists, insert the value in the second table and then commit. Read up on this and write an attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the database verify that the data is unique.  For instance, if the triple of `d1, d2, d3` is supposed to be unique, then create a unique index/constraint on those columns:

```
create unique index idx_content2_d1_d2_d3 on content2(d1, d2, d3);
```

Then if you try to insert a row, you'll get an error.  You can get around this error using `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO content2(d1, d2, d3)
    SELECT d1, d2, d3
    FROM content
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d1 = values(d1);
```

The update doesn't actually change any values.  It simply prevents an error from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO content2 (d1,d2,d3)
SELECT c1.d1,c1.d2,c1.d3 from content c1
Where   not exists (
       select *
       from content2 as c2
       where c1.d1 = c2.d1 and c1.d2 = c2.d2 and c1.d3 = c2.d3
   )
```

Hope this will help

[Fiddle for selecting the row from c1 which not exist in c2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/996b7/3)

COnsidering you are checking entire row as containing before inserting thats why condition is for d1,d2,d3. IF only need to check any of the column you can avoid others

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Gordon Linoff's answer, it is also possible to achieve this result without generating error messages using `INSERT IGNORE`.

Your query will look like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO content2 (d1, d2, d3) SELECT d1, d2, d3 FROM content
```

If the data you're attempting to insert into `content2` contains a primary key that already exists in the table, it will be skipped. Instead of generating an error message, this will generate a warning. The record will be created if it does not already exist in the table.